# How to sync Sprite Flip in Unity with Photon2

Tags: unity-game-engine, multiplayer, photon

I am trying to sync a sprite flip in a multiplayer 2d game , the sprite flips on the local player but the other player does not see the flip. The flip is in the code with the movement , the movement syncs no problem. Could it be something about the Sprite Renderer Component and somehow syncing that ?

```
if (movement > 0f)
        {
            rigidBody.velocity = new Vector2(groundMovementSpeed , rigidBody.velocity.y);

            SR.flipX = false;

        }
        if (movement < 0f)
        {
            rigidBody.velocity = new Vector2(-groundMovementSpeed , rigidBody.velocity.y);

            SR.flipX = true;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

to synch a boolean value with Photon 2, you need to use a component with an IPunObservable, observed by a PhotonView. more infos here:

https://doc.photonengine.com/en-us/pun/current/gameplay/synchronization-and-state

if you are new Photon, you should go over the basic tutorial, it will cover what you are after:

https://doc.photonengine.com/en-us/pun/current/demos-and-tutorials/pun-basics-tutorial/player-networking#beams_fire_control

you would do the same things as the isFiring bool in this tutorial.